# How to add Postgres extension when pushing local database to Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, heroku-postgres

I have a Django application which relies upon the `postgis` Postgres extension.

I want to copy my local Database to Heroku using `pg:push`, but I get numerous `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation does not exist` errors, following on from:

```
pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR:  type "public.geography" does not exist
LINE 6:     coords public.geography(Point,4326),
                   ^
Command was: CREATE TABLE public.outreach_localcompanylocation (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    long_name character varying(200) NOT NULL,
    city character varying(200) NOT NULL,
    country character varying(3) NOT NULL,
    coords public.geography(Point,4326),
    google_location_id bigint,
    state character varying(200)
);
```

This seems to be because `pg:push` does not enable the `postgis` extension (typically enabled by running the SQL command `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;`).

If I try to enable it manually on a new Heroku database, then run `pg:push`, I get this error:

`Remote database is not empty. Please create a new database or use heroku pg:reset`

So is there a way to run `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;` as part of the `pg:push` process?

Comment: Do you get the ```django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation does not exist``` error before the push is successful or after its been pushed and you try to read from the db?

Comment: @nstvnsn before. The error does not stop the push from completing, but it does show up in the log as it's running the push.

Comment: From the relation errors, I'm thinking a migration issue with Django. Have you made changes to the app that may need a migration? I left an answer with the solution to what I think the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

The docs indicate you cannot push to a non-empty database:

> ...To prevent accidental data overwrites and loss, the remote database must be empty. You’ll be prompted to pg:reset a remote database that isn’t empty...

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/managing-heroku-postgres-using-cli#pg-push

Also, are you doing your migrations? The fact that django is spitting relation errors makes me think it is leaning that way.

1. Delete the files in your local app's migrations folder, leave the `__init__.py` file there.
2. Run `python manage.py makemigrations`
3. Run `python manage.py migrate`
4. Reset the heroku database so it's empty and ready for you to push.
5. Deploy app with updated migrations to heroku.
6. Run `heroku run python manage.py migrate`

Comment: This didn't work, I think it's because without `postgis` I keep getting the `type "public.geography" does not exist` error. 

I've switched to Render.com instead of Heroku which has fixed it.

Comment: Yeah it's like a catch 22. You need postgis for the push, but if you have it activated on the remote db the push fails. Because remote db has to empty as a precaution to avoid data loss. Hmm.

Comment: Oh, maybe a dumb question. Did you try enabling the postgis extention on you local db, ensure that the remote db was empty with a ```pg:reset```, then try push your local to remote?

Comment: Yes I did. Also `pg:reset` does not remove the extension, I have to remove it and also `pg:reset`

Comment: And after removing the extension manually and resetting the remote db, adding the extension to your local db, and then pg:push, same issues? I can see why you switched to Render.

Comment: Yes, same issue. `pg:push` doesn't seem to include the extension when pushing.